# Get a list of all enabled block deltas

Tags: 7, blocks

I need an array of all enabled blocks' deltas.

For example, if I display the array, it should output the block deltas e.g. search_form, user_new, user_login, *and not the block titles e.g Search, User* etc

I've found a few candidates:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_list/7

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21modules%21block%21block.module/function/block_get_blocks_by_region/7

But they all crash my site. Really can't get it to work, please give some examples that works for you.

Comment: You mean you need the `delta` of the blocks, and not the `title`? (it should output e.g. search_form, user_new, user_login and not search, user etc)

Comment: yeah, indeed, I hope you understand what I desire to achieve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine why your site is crashing using the two functions you link to (Drupal calls them both internally so it certainly shouldn't be), but you can use the following custom query to grab that data directly from the database:

```
$query = db_select('block', 'b')
  ->condition('theme', $your_theme_name)
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('region', -1, '<>');

$query->addExpression("CONCAT(module, '_', delta)", 'delta');

$deltas = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

// $deltas now contains a list of deltas for all enabled blocks in the provided theme
```

Comment: I seriously wanted to thank you again! Thanks to this I  was able to finish my project. I developed a module, which I will donate to the community, partly thanks to you Clive! If you like I will inform you as soon as the modules has been donated