# How to get values of delta field from "block" table in drupal 7 from the database for the activated theme in a custom module?

Tags: 7, database

Can I get all the values of delta field from "block" table from the database in my custom module

I have tried with this code as clive has explained it [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36055/get-a-list-of-all-enabled-block-deltas) but it shows me an error:

```
 $query = db_select('module__block', 'b')
  ->condition('theme', $business)
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('region', -1, '<>');


    $query->addExpression("CONCAT('_', delta)", 'delta');
    $deltas = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
    print_r($deltas);
```

`module__block` : Is the name of the block table since I attached a prefix to it.

Comment: Never attach prefixes defined in config.php to table names manually. For db_select use unprefixed name. For db_query use name in {fancy parenthesis}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT delta, 
FROM  `module__block` 
WHERE theme LIKE  'business'
LIMIT 0 , 30 ;
```

shows only blocks.

SELECT delta, theme
FROM  `module__block` 
WHERE theme LIKE  'business'
LIMIT 0 , 30;

It will shows both the block names and theme name.